# Number of choices

Tags: probability, combinatorics

During our class today, we solved the following problem:

> In a class with 14 girls and 7 boys, 6 will be chosen. Their
> order doesn't matter. How many sets can you form with at
> least one girl and one boy?

My first approach was to select one boy and one girl, and then draw from the remaining people, like this:

$$
7 * 14 * {19 \choose 4} = 379848
$$

This, of course, yields the incorrect result, since the number is more significant than the total number of choices: ${21 \choose 6} = 54246$. I guess the error is related to the fact that  I'm double-counting permutations, but can't fix it.

My teacher subtracts the number of sets with only girls and only boys from the total, which makes sense, but I can't understand what is wrong with my answer and how to correct it.

I hope someone out there can. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your method counts the number of groups with at least one girl and one boy, with a *choice* of one girl and one boy. [Imagine giving a sticker to the one boy and one girl you choose first.]

Comment: If the group has boys Alan and Bob, you've counted the case twice, once when you choose Alan first, and once when you choose Bob first. In general, you've counted each group $gb$ times, where $g$ is the number of girls in the group, and $b$ the number of boys.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews That makes sense, but how can I correct it? I've tried a number of options, but can't get it right. Or is it just too complex and I should just stick with my teacher's version?

Comment: It is just too complex. In general, if the question is "with $n$ or more" somethings, it is not going to be very efficient to first select $n.$ You could pick the first boy and first girl of the committee, alphabetically, but that gets you:$$\sum_{b=1}^7\sum_{g=1}^{12}\binom{19-(b+g)}4.$$ That's **a** correct answer, but not the best way to calculate it.

Comment: this has nothing to do with group theory. Perhaps remove the tag.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thank you very much! Why don't you make it into an answer?

Comment: @BrauerSuzuki Sorry for that :)